# How to add prefix to folder name using wildcard without using Powershell

Tags: windows, rename, batch-rename

i wanna create a batch script to rename `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.GamingServices_4.66.30001.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe` to `+Microsoft.GamingServices_4.66.30001.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe` but version number might be changed after updating, so i want use wildcard, but cant use `Ren` because it cant rename folder with wildcard and also cant use `Move` because it cant add prefix to folder. i dont want use powershell because i wanna add it to context menu for toggle enable/disable gaming service so speed important for me, (powershell is so slow).

i tried it before:

```
move /Y "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\+Microsoft.GamingServices_*" "+Microsoft.GamingServices_*"
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running as a .bat file:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps"
for /D %%a in ("Microsoft.GamingServices_*") do ren "%%a" "+%%a"
```

Running from commandline:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps"
for /D %a in ("Microsoft.GamingServices_*") do ren "%a" "+%a"
```

This will loop through the folders in the current directory (C:\Program Files\WindowsApps) and find the folder (Microsoft.GamingServices_*) with wildcard for version variation and prepend a plus sign to the directory.