# How to use Command-line to batch-rename the FOLDER prefix using wildcards

Tags: command-line, rename, batch-rename, wildcards

So it has been mentioned that `REN` can be used to rename a FOLDER, but wildcards are not allowed.

I have a directory with a couple of hundred FOLDERS, where I want to remove the first seven characters (aka prefix) from all the FOLDER names.

For example, the current folder name might be "*ABC DE PIZZA*", and I want to strip the "*ABC DE* " from the folder name, with just the "PIZZA" folder name remaining.

I saw another answer (https://superuser.com/a/1739002/368970) with this command line solution that uses the wildcard to leave the base folder name intact and adds a plus sign to the front of the FOLDER name (aka prefix):

```
cd "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps" for /D %a in 
("Microsoft.GamingServices_*") do ren "%a" "+%a"
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can use command-line to remove the first 7 character prefix from all the folders in a directory, but leave all the remaining characters beyond that 7 character prefix intact?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: A Community-bot asked me to clarify my problem.  hehe.   Here's my question: How I can use command-line to remove the first 7 character-prefix from all the folders in a directory, but leave all the remaining characters beyond that 7 character-prefix, intact?

Comment: The bot knows its stuff... since the question is not easy to understand in the way it was written (known as a Wall of Text...) without paragraphs and formatting... (BTW, I guided you to also link to the other answer that you're referring to.... https://superuser.com/a/1739002/368970)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With PowerShell you can easily do that using (based on https://superuser.com/a/273220/368970):

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse | rename-item -newname { [string]($_.name).substring(7) }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with this `.bat` file :

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /d %%i in (*) do (
  set tmp=%%i
  ren "!tmp!" "!tmp:~7!"
)
```

Explanation :

- [for /d](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html) enumerates folders inside
  the current directory
- [EnableDelayedExpansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)
  causes variables to be expanded at execution time
  and uses `!` for delayed expansion
- The syntax to skip the first 7 characters is explained in the post
  [What is the best way to do a substring in a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636381/what-is-the-best-way-to-do-a-substring-in-a-batch-file)
- I used the temporary variable `tmp` because the substring
  syntax using `~` does not work inside a FOR loop.

Comment: Thank you so much!  Unfortunately, I don't know how to use that .bat logic in command prompt (or use it at all). I'm horrible.

I know this ren function below will rename the FOLDER, but it only works when I have the full current and desired FOLDER names in the function. And of course we can't use wildcards to rename FOLDERS.

ren "\\full network path\ABC DE FOLDER TWO" "FOLDER TWO"

Comment: Hello, In this .bat code, where do I indicate the parent FOLDER location where the children FOLDERS are being renamed?  

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /d %%i in (*) do (
  set tmp=%%i
  ren "!tmp!" "!tmp:~7!"
)

Comment: The simplest solution would be to store the `.bat` file inside the directory and launch it from there. Otherwise, the syntax is similar to `for /d %%i in (C:\folder)`.

Comment: Hello, Well, I have 4 test folder in a directory, and I've only been able to remove the first 7 characters of the FOLDER when I copied the 4 test folders over to my C:\Users\RMaltase and used this .bat code.    ...but when I try to run this .bat from another directory, I can't get it to work.  It's so odd, because you can see that the code is finding my 4 test FOLDERS, (TEN, ELEVEN, TWELVE, THIRTEEN) but it won't remove the first 7 characters.   Any thoughts?    ...and on a related note, I've tried 34 .bat versions to try and remove the "SSA RI ".   That's actually what I'd really like to do.

Comment: This is my .bat code and what is shows in the cmd screen when it runs:

Comment: the code:    
pushd "\\ccal-nas-001b\dept\gssarevint\COMMAND PROMPT TEST\"  EnableDelayedExpansion
for /d %%i in (*) do (set tmp=%%i ren "!tmp!" "!tmp:~7!")

Comment: The Results in the cmd screen:
R:\COMMAND PROMPT TEST>pushd "\\ccal-nas-001b\dept\gssarevint\COMMAND PROMPT TEST\"  
EnableDelayedExpansion The system cannot find the path specified.
R:\COMMAND PROMPT TEST>for / %i in (*) do (set tmp=%i ren "!tmp!" "!tmp:~7!" ) 
R:\COMMAND PROMPT TEST>(set tmp=SSA RI FOLDER TEN ren "!tmp!" "!tmp:~7!" ) 
R:\COMMAND PROMPT TEST>(set tmp=SSA RI FOLDER ELEVEN ren "!tmp!" "!tmp:~7!" ) 
R:\COMMAND PROMPT TEST>(set tmp=SSA RI FOLDER TWELVE ren "!tmp!" "!tmp:~7!" ) 
R:\COMMAND PROMPT TEST>(set tmp=SSA RI FOLDER THIRTEEN ren "!tmp!" "!tmp:~7!" )

Comment: Hello @harrymc, can you please help me figure out how to strip-off or remove part of all of the FOLDER names in a directory --- using a .bat? I’m trying to remove this 7 character string “SSA RI ” (including the middle and trailing space). I just want to remove this string “SSA RI ” from any FOLDER name where it is included in the FOLDER name. If the FOLDER does not include that string in the name, there should be no changes made to the FOLDER name. I think i'm making people mad here.  :-(

Comment: It might be easier with PowerShell.

Comment: It was, for sure.  Still, Thank you for your help.  :-)