# Can I use a .bat file to rename all the FOLDERS in a directory?

Tags: command-line, batch-file, batch-rename

Can anyone please help me figure out how to strip-off or remove part of all of the FOLDER names in a directory? I’m trying to remove this 7 character string “SSA RI ” (including the middle and trailing space). I just want to remove this string “SSA RI ” from any FOLDER name where it is included in the FOLDER name. If the FOLDER does not include that string in the name, there should be no changes made to the FOLDER name.

Comment: Could you put all this additional information into your question, via the [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1793447/edit) button.

Comment: @ron your question is very unclear and is missing info. Edit it and put all details from the comments into the question, but also add a link to the question you are referring to (where harrymc answered you) and explain why his code isn't good.

Comment: I'm so sorry.  Thank you for your guidance.

Comment: It's still illegible. Try to rewrite it with more focus and details. Also, please use the `{}` button in the editor to paste the code samples

Comment: @YisroelTech: A modified version of your [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1790664/8672) is more suitable here.

Comment: @harrymc If only the question would be clear enough to gather what his real issue is with the solutions there

Comment: @YisroelTech: He's probably looking to remove the sub-string "SSA RI ".

Answer (score 1):

To rename all directories and subdirectories that start with `SSA RI`  stripping this prefix, you can run this PowerShell script:

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse | foreach {
    $newName = $_.Name
    if ($newName -like "SSA RI *") {
        $newName = $newName.Substring(7)
    }
    if ($newName -ne $_.Name) {
        Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $newName
    }
}
```

If you want to remove `SSA RI`  from the folder name even if it appers in the middle of the name you can use:

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse | foreach {
    $newName = $_.Name -replace "SSA RI ", ""
    if ($newName -ne $_.Name) {
        Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $newName
    }
}
```

Comment: Although you didn't use a .bat as the OP requested, this is a much better answer than they asked for.  Sure .bat could have done this easily.. as long as there were no `&` in the folder name etc etc.

Comment: Hello, Can anyone help me with this question, using a .bat method? I don't have PowerShell, and can't use it on my work pc.  thanks.

Comment: What does "*I don't have PowerShell*" mean? Windows comes with PowerShell

Comment: Thanks @Yisroel Tech.  Basically, It means I'm an idiot and don't know what I'm doing.  I'll open up PowerShell and give it a shot.  Thanks again.

Comment: It worked!!! Thank you, thank you. so very much @Yisroel Tech.       
I added the Set-Location code, and pow!   

Set-Location -Path "\\ccal-nas-001b\dept\gssarevint\COMMAND PROMPT TEST\"
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse | foreach {
    $newName = $_.Name -replace "SSA RI ", ""
    if ($newName -ne $_.Name) {
        Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $newName
    }
}